# Assembly language - a 3d array arrangement in stack frame

Tags: assembly, x86

I have a 3D array and I want to deal with the value of say `c[l][i][k]`..

- c is in the location `16(%ebp)`
- l is in `-24(%ebp)`
- i is in `-20(%ebp)`
- k is in `-12(%ebp)`

The array size is `[20][20][20]`

The assembly code for this is

```
movl    -24(%ebp), %eax          #eax <-- l
imull   $1600, %eax, %eax        #eax <--1600*l 
movl    %eax, %ecx               #ecx <--1600*l
addl    16(%ebp), %ecx           #ecx <--1600*l + c 
movl    -20(%ebp), %edx          #edx <-- i
movl    %edx, %eax               #eax <-- i
sall    $2, %eax                
addl    %edx, %eax              
sall    $2, %eax            
addl    -12(%ebp), %eax             
movl    -8(%ebp), %edx              
movl    %edx, (%ecx,%eax,4)
```

1. what is the significance of each of the assembly code lines here?
2. How do we actually get the value `c[l][i][k]`?
3. Also what is the line `movl  %edx, (%ecx,%eax,4)` doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That array is represented as a contiguous sequence of `20 * 20 * 20 * (size of one element)` bytes. The address of element `[l][i][k]` inside this array can be computed as follows:

```
   l * 20 * 20 * size of one element
 + i * 20 * size of one element
 + k * size of one element
```

The multiplication `1600 * l` does the first step - `l * 20 * 20 * (size of one element)` bytes (which suggests that size is 4 bytes).

The lines you haven't commented compute `(((i << 2) + i) << 2) + k` , which is essentially `20 * i + k` - the second and third steps combined, sans the multiplication by element size. (`sall` is "shift left", same as C's bitwise shift.)

This missing multiplication is done by the last line: `movl %edx (%ecx, %eax, 4)` computes `ecx + eax * 4` (the address we want) and puts the value of `edx` into that address.

Note that this code appears to be *writing* into the array, not reading from it, like your question suggests. To *read* that element from the array, you should use that parenthesized expression as the first argument of `movl`.